# Why is py_varo being printed as opposed to the value in the textbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.3

For some reason when I press the button py_varo is being printed rather than the value in the textbox. Any idea why?

```
import sys
from tkinter import*

mygui = Tk()
message = StringVar()
mygui.geometry('300x300+982+0')
mygui.title("hey everyone check out my gui")
mylabel1 = Label(mygui, text = 'hello world',fg = 'yellow', bg = 'blue')
mylabel1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
def button():
    global message
    print (message)
textbox = Entry(mygui, textvariable =message)
textbox.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
mybutton = Button(mygui, text = 'Pointless Button', command = button)
mybutton.grid(row = 0,column = 1)

mygui.mainloop()
```

Comment: *for the asker of this question*, please do accept and respond to the answers you receive for questions as that's what keeps stackoverflow running for example for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585560/my-tkinter-gui-is-invisible-for-unknown-reasons) of yours you have a recieved a excellent answer from @falsetru however you have neither commented or accepted.... please avoid the ask and run model of yours.... also consider [taking a tour about SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

This occurs since your not getting the value in the `StringVar` which is done using the `get()` method

So Change your `button()` function to this:

```
def button():
    global message
    print (message.get())
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace following line:

```
print(message)
```

with (Use `get` method of the StringVar object):

```
print(message.get())
```

Otherwise it print the variable itself, not content of the variable.